# search multiple and exact pattern to replace with sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I've a mutiple domains following with hostnames.

```
abc-ddddd-guru.prod.gama1.com
ddf-yy1.gama1.com
ccd-dlf89-01.cdfgama1.com
kk1-dlf88.gg1-gama1.com
radaas.gama1.com
```

when i try to add ilo before each domain name with sed .. its not happening exactly

`#sed 's/gama1.com/-ilo.gama1.com/g; s/cdfgama1.com/-ilo.cdfgama1.com/g' ; s/gg1-gama1.com/-ilo.gg1-gama1.com/g' ; s/prod.gama1.com/-ilo.prod.gama1.com/g`'

OP :

```
abc-ddddd-guru.prod.-ilo.gama1.com
    ddf-yy1.-ilo.gama1.com
    ccd-dlf89-01.cdf-ilo.gama1.com
    kk1-dlf88.gg1--ilo.gama1.com
    radaas.-ilo.gama1.com
```

Please help .. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this sed

```
sed -E 's/([^.]*\.)(.*gama1.com$)/\1-ilo.\2/' infile
```

Or this awk

```
awk '/gama1.com$/{sub(/\./,".-ilo.")}1' infile
```

Answer (score 2):

**`sed`** solution:

```
sed -E 's/([^.]*|prod\.)?gama1.com$/-ilo.&/' file
```

- `([^.]*|prod\.)?` - regex alternation group, matches either any char except `.` (presented by `[^.]*`) or `prod.` subdomain name. 
   `?` quantifier tells to match the mentioned group between zero and one times
- `&` - *sed*'s replacement value, points to the whole match

---

The output:

```
abc-ddddd-guru.-ilo.prod.gama1.com
ddf-yy1.-ilo.gama1.com
ccd-dlf89-01.-ilo.cdfgama1.com
kk1-dlf88.-ilo.gg1-gama1.com
radaas.-ilo.gama1.com
```

Comment: That's a great answer. It worked on all of the domains except only one domain.. 

ccd-ddf23-312.prod.-ilo.gama1.com . 

could you explain pls the answer also

Comment: @DasD, yes, see my explanation. And why did you note that it won't work with `ccd-ddf23-312.prod.-ilo.gama1.com` - how that relates with your last substitution attempt `s/prod.gama1.com/-ilo.prod.gama1.com/g` ?

Comment: not sure where did i missing and  why its failing but last pattern i'm getting o/p like this 
ccd-ddf23-312.prod.-ilo.gama1.com

Comment: @DasD, that's because your question was ambiguous

Answer (score 2):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk -v var="-ilo." '{match($0,/gama1.com/);print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) var substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation too now with solution.

```
awk -v var="-ilo." '                                        ##Creating variable named var and have its value as -ilo. as per OP request.
{
  match($0,/gama1.com/);                                    ##Using match utility of awk by which we could use a regex and could match the specific needed part of a line. Its pattern is match(var/line,regex). If regex has a match on a line then out of the box variables named RSTART and RLENGTH will be having values in it. Where RSTART will have the starting value of matching regex and RLENGTH will have the length of matched regex by match utility.
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) var substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) ##Printing the substring here which starts from 1st letter to till the value of RSTART-1(means just before the match) print everything then print variable var here then again print substring of line whose value starts from RSTART to RLENGTH to print the exact match in line.
}
' Input_file                                                ##Mentioning the Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a posting, not what to do, but how to do it.

Alignment is king:

```
     's/gama1.com/-ilo.gama1.com/g; 
   s/cdfgama1.com/-ilo.cdfgama1.com/g; 
  s/gg1-gama1.com/-ilo.gg1-gama1.com/g; 
 s/prod.gama1.com/-ilo.prod.gama1.com/g'
```

we see the common pattern aligned vertically and can separate the common part and the uncommon one.

```
's/(prod\.|gg1-|cdf)?gama1.com/-ilo.\1.gama1.com/g'
```

Are prod/gg1/cdf just random examples? I don't know. Maybe it's just a group of lower case characters and digits. Alternatives can be combined with OR:=|, but have to be grouped with parens, else abc|def would match (abcef OR abdef), not (abc OR def). With extensive usage of parens, sed needs the -r switch for extended regular expressions, or you have to mask the parens:

```
's/(([a-z0-9]+\.)|([a-z0-9]+-)|([a-z0-9]+))?gama1.com/-ilo.\1.gama1.com/g'
```

This can be condensed further, to letters, optionally followed by dot or minus:

```
 sed -r 's/(([a-z0-9]+)[.-]?)?gama1.com/-ilo.\2.gama1.com/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me perl code looks nice:

```
perl -ne 'print "$1-ilo$2\n" if /^([\w-]+)(.+)/'
```